# Having problems distinguishing between multiple ImageButton objects sharing the same Clicked event in Xamarin Forms Visual Studio 2019

Tags: xamarin.forms

Hello Guys I'm new at xamarin forms and I  a nooby question thanks. OK I have four imagebuttons on a contentpage and I want to bind them to a OnImageButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e).  But how would I bind the 4 imagebuttons ?    thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ImageButton ClassID="A" Clicked="OnImageButtonClicked" ... />
<ImageButton ClassID="B" Clicked="OnImageButtonClicked" ... />

protected void OnImageButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs a)
{
  Button btn = (Button)sender;

  if (btn.ClassID == "A") {
    ...
  }

  if (btn.ClassID == "B") {
    ...
  }
}
```